# calling a synchronized method from run method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an Account model and I want to withdraw it synchronously. But even after making the method synchronized and calling it from run method there is still some troubles in the order of outputs. Here is my code. I really don't know what is the problem.

```
public class Account {
private double balance;
public Account(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}
public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
}


public class WithdrawThread implements Runnable {
private double amount;
private Account account;

public WithdrawThread(Account account, double amount) {
    this.account = account;
    this.amount = amount;
}

public synchronized void withdraw(double amount) {

    double bal = account.getBalance();
    if (amount > account.getBalance())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong amount");
    bal -= amount;
    account.setBalance(bal);
    System.out.println(amount + " withdraw in thread number" +        Thread.currentThread().getId() + " balance is " + bal);
}

public void run() {
    withdraw(amount);
}
```

}

```
public class MainThread {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Account account = new Account(200);
    new Thread(new WithdrawThread(account, 40)).start();
    new Thread(new WithdrawThread(account, 10)).start();
    new Thread(new WithdrawThread(account, 10)).start();
    new Thread(new WithdrawThread(account, 20)).start();
    new Thread(new WithdrawThread(account, 30)).start();
    new Thread(new WithdrawThread(account, 10)).start();
    new Thread(new WithdrawThread(account, 40)).start();
}
}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: When you use the `synchronized` keyword in a method definition, Java synchronizes on the current object (`this`). You have 7 different objects. They are not coordinated at all.

Comment: +1 to Sotorios. withdraw() should be a method of Account, and this method should be synchronized. Of course, the other ones (setBalance(), getBalance()) should also be synchronized since they all access the shared mutable balance.

Comment: But I dont want to move the method to the Account class because there might be several other methods. How can I coordinate all objects ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by Sotirios Delimanolis, a synchronized method uses a lock from the object it is called on, which is the WithdrawThread instance. You want to lock the Account...

Either make withdraw an Account method, or use a synchronized block.

```
public void withdraw(double amount) {
    double bal;
    synchronized(account) {
        bal = account.getBalance();
        if (amount > account.getBalance())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong amount");
        bal -= amount;
        account.setBalance(bal);
    }
    System.out.println(amount + " withdraw in thread number" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " balance is " + bal);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you `synchronize` you synchronize on a specific object. It then stops other people from synchronizing on that object until you have finished.

When you don't specify an object it synchronizes on `this`.

So each of your threads has synchronized on itself.

Instead you need to use a synchronized block inside the method and synchronize on a common object, such as the `Account` being modified.

```
public void withdraw(double amount) {
    synchronized (account) {
        double bal = account.getBalance();
        if (amount > account.getBalance())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong amount");
        bal -= amount;
        account.setBalance(bal);
        System.out.println(amount + " withdraw in thread number" +        Thread.currentThread().getId() + " balance is " + bal);
   }
}
```